# In Clojure how could I create an "add id to map" function?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Say I have a collection of maps:

```
(def coll #{{:name "foo"} {:name "bar"}})
```

I want a function that will add an id (a unique number is fine) to each map element in the collection. i.e.

```
#{{:id 1 :name "foo"} {:id 2 :name "bar"}}
```

The following DOES NOT WORK, but it's the line of thinking I currently have.

```
(defn add-unique-id [coll]
(map assoc :id (iterate inc 0) coll))
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
(defn add-unique-id [coll]
  (map #(assoc  %1 :id %2)  coll (range (count coll))))
```

Or

```
(defn add-unique-id [coll]
  (map #(assoc  %1 :id %2)  coll (iterate inc 0)))
```

Comment: Ah! Your second function is exactly what I was trying to do with the laziness. Thank you!

Comment: Might as well just use (range), since that's equivalent to your iterate

Answer (score 11):

If you want to be really, really sure the IDs are unique, use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier)s.

```
(defn add-id [coll]
  (map #(assoc % :id (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))) coll))
```

Comment: Thank you, Brian. I wish I could award two right answers. Bugspy.net's accomplishes exactly what I'm looking for, but I am keeping yours in mind if true uniqueness becomes important.